# Filterpredicate with json array filter

Tags: angular

I have a filter that is pretty simple:

```
this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify({
    state: this.searchForm.controls['stateInputControl'].value,
    product: this.searchForm.controls['productInputControl'].value
});
```

However, I need to add a filter predicate because I need to have an or statement for the state.  If I just had the state being passed, the filter predicate would be simple:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data,filter:string ) => {
        return (data.state == filter || data.state == "AL")
      };
```

However, the filter isn't just a string it's a json array. So I need to do something like this:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data,filter:{state:string,product:string} ) => {
        return ((data.state == filter.state || data.state == "AL") && data.product == filter.product)
      };
```

This throws an error however:

> Type '(data: Guide, filter: { state: string; product: string; }) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(data: Guide, filter: string) => boolean'.
>   Types of parameters 'filter' and 'filter' are incompatible.
>   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ state: string; product: string; }'.

How do I use filterPredicate with a filter that is a json array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined the solution.  You simply take in the serialized JSON and then parse the JSON inside of the filter predicate declaration, like so:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data,filter:string ) => {
        var s = JSON.Parse(filter);
        return ((data.state == s.state || data.state == "AL") && data.product == s.product)
      };
```

filterPredicate should also handle null/unknown/blank values as well which are possible and will screw up filtering.  A better formatting of this filterpredicate would be:

```
     var s = JSON.parse(filter);
      if (s.state && s.state.length && data.state !== s.state && data.state !== 'AL' && data.state !== '') { return false }
      else if (s.product && s.product.length && data.product !== s.product) { return false }
      return true;
```